# How to write macros?

Tags: macros, mathjax

I'm very new to TeX and am only learning it to write in MathJax on the math stackexchange.  I've just discovered that I can write macros to make it easier to do repeated things, but I'm having some difficulty with how macros work.

It would appear that [`\def`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/def) defines a macro that is delimited by strings (a series of tokens).  So:

```
\def\foo[#1]#2{The\ first\ argument\ is\ ''#1'',\ the\ second\ one\ is\ ''#2''}
\foo[hi]there
```

results in:

> *The first argument is ′′hi′′, the second one is ′′t′′here*

and if I want all of 'there' as the second argument, I'd do this:

```
\foo[hi]{there}
```

resulting in:

> *The first argument is ′′hi′′, the second one is ′′there′′*

But is there a way to get it so that I could put braces around the entire section that contains all of the parameters, instead of having to put braces around the last parameter?  Such as:

```
\foo{[hi]there}
```

Comment: There are no strings (in the sense you'll mean) in TeX, there are tokens! I'm not sure what you mean about braces: can you add an example?

Comment: @JosephWright, added example at the end.

Comment: If this is going to be used on mathjax, this is probably not the proper place to ask. There information on this in the doc pages at mathjax.org. Generally, you should not expect mathjax to support user defined macros. It can be made to support some, but it has to be done at its configuration level, whichy you as the user cannot access.

Comment: That's just a macro with one argument: ``\def\foo#1{I saw `#1'}``

Comment: If you are a new LaTeX user, sharelatex or overleaf might be better places to start with LaTeX as mathjax is not LaTeX, it is just a JS lib that can interpret at subpart of LaTeX

Comment: what do you use for learning LaTeX?

Comment: @touhami, just snippets I get from this site and the internet.

Comment: @daleif, as MathJax is a subset of LaTeX, then if I ask a question about MathJax, should it not be in the domain of LaTeX?

Comment: try to find a good doc in your natural language : `\def` is not latex it's tex primitive and you don't need `\ ` each time for a space you can just left a white space (or more than one).

Comment: MathJax is the wrong tool for learning LaTeX; the main limitation is that it always does math mode, which is not good when you have text to write.

Comment: @touhami, sorry if I'm getting the terminology incorrect.  I'll correct.  The `\\` I guess are an artifact of MathJax.

Comment: @Adrian different technologies, jut because it can understand a subset of LaTeX does not make it LaTeX. Most people can understand what `x^2+y^2=z^2` but that does not make them into LaTeX interpreters. Either Install LaTeX and a decent editor on your computer, or use sharelatex/overleaf

Comment: @JosephWright Isn't this off-topic if it is MathJax?

Comment: @cfr Only if it's not also applicable to TeX: here I'm thinking it probably is OK

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. I realised it wasn't as you'd commented, but wanted to know the rationale as I had expected it would be. (Don't want to vote to close another question which shouldn't be closed, if I can avoid it.)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  It is done by a level of indirection:

```
\def\foo#1{\foox#1\\}
\def\foox[#1]#2\\{The\ first\ argument\ is\ ''#1'',\ the\ second\ one\ is\ ''#2''}
\foo{[hi]there}
```

Basically, I need to specify a termination token.  So, `\foo` will call with a single token (stuff within the `{`/`}` characters), which in turn calls `\foox` with a termination character of `\\`.

Comment: Note that this only makes sense if `\foo` is to be used exclusively in maths mode.